# How to resize div element from right to left and top to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add resize property to div. However I want it to change its width and height only in right and bottom directions. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
<style>
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: -1313px;
    top: 89px;
    width: 316px;
    resize:both;
    height: 333px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(208,208,208,0.4); 
}
</style>
<div class="modal">
</div>
```

Comment: you must to add your code if you want somebody to help you

Comment: try this #yourDIV {
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto;  
}

Comment: How does one drag a resize corner when one cannot grab it? `left: -1313px;`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting margin-left and margin-top values to 0.